# Swift 4 Functions Button properties

Tags: swift, xcode

I am very new to Swift. I am trying to create func

```
func roundedButton(buttonik: String) {       
    buttonik.clipsToBounds = true
    buttonik.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    buttonik.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
}
```

Than call it

```
roundedButton(buttonik: "buttonTop")
```

and have this output

```
buttonTop.clipsToBounds = true
buttonTop.layer.cornerRadius = 10
buttonTop.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

I am getting these errors

```
Value of type 'String' has no member 'clipsToBounds'
Value of type 'String' has no member 'layer'
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are confusing the name of a button with the object that represents that button.  Change your routine to:

```
func roundedButton(button: UIButton) {       
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
}
```

Then call it by passing the button you want to apply these properties to... instead of passing it a string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting your `buttonik` parameter to be a `UIButton`, but you're declaring it as a `String`. Since `String` does not support the properties you're trying to modify, you're getting compilation errors. If you declare it as a `UIButton` instead, your code should compile.

Comment: Well, she would also have to pass in the actual button object instead of the name of the variable as a `String`.